# How many different alkyl chlorides result from C4H10 and chlorine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, isomers, radicals

Let's say there's a reaction $\ce{C4H10 + Cl2}$ taking place under UV light. How many different alkyl chlorides do we obtain?

I'm not sure if the resulting molecule would be monochlorinated or dichlorinated? My guess was monochlorinated, as $\ce{HCl}$ is also going to be a product. And I assumed there would be 2 different alkyl chlorides as there are two different possibilities for a chlorine to be attached to a carbon of a butane.  But I guess I was wrong as the answer the book gives is 4 and not 2. How can the book’s answer be rationalised?

Comment: I guess that your "C4H10" was a mixture of n-butane and isobutane.

Comment: Well, that is probably it because I don't see how there would be 4 possibilities for an n-butane. I thought that I maybe was missing something somehow and that I was supposed to attach two chlorines instead of one, but I can't see something like that happening. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If you were to attach two Cl, that would make **more** than 4 isomers, even if we stick to n-butane, and even if we disregard mono-Cl stuff.

Comment: The question needs clarification. Does C4H10 mean n-butane and/or isobutane? Such questions usually state monochloro alkyl halides. What does "different" mean? Constitutional (structural) isomers or stereoisomers?